# How to create dynamic pivot query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create dynamic pivot query in SQL but my issue is that the contract id and the tier desc columns are both dynamic and I could not figure out how to solve this issue. I have something like this:

[image]

and this is the output I would like to see

[image]

Comment: You can't have all three columns in your output named "tier value".   Each column needs a different name.   In what way is this pivot dynamic?

Comment: okay but my goal to display the corresponding tier value for each contract id so how do i do that?  thanks

Comment: You say display. Can they be delimited in one column? If so, use a group by and the FOR XML STUFF. Just google those words if you want the delimited list

Comment: @TabAlleman "can't" is a really big word.   I think the key word here is "shouldn't"   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *can* be done with repeating column names, however, I can't imagine why one would want this.

The @Col is where we apply the Alias `...[#] as [Tier Value]...`

**Example**

```
Declare @Col varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + concat(QuoteName(row_number() over (Partition By ContractID Order by TierDesc)),' as [Tier Value]') From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(row_number() over (Partition By ContractID Order by TierDesc)) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Select  @SQL = '
Select ContractID,'+@Col+'
 From (  
        Select ContractID
              ,TierDesc
              ,ColNr = row_number() over (Partition By ContractID Order by TierDesc) 
         From  YourTable
      ) Src
 Pivot (max(TierDesc) for ColNr in ('+@SQL+') ) pvt
 '
 Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
ContractID  Tier Value  Tier Value  Tier Value
123         tier1       tier2       NULL
555         tier4       tier5       tier6
652         tier0       tier4       NULL
```

> **EDIT - Then generated SQL Looks like this**

```
Select ContractID
      ,[1] as [Tier Value]
      ,[2] as [Tier Value]
      ,[3] as [Tier Value]
 From (  
        Select ContractID
              ,TierDesc
              ,ColNr = row_number() over (Partition By ContractID Order by TierDesc) 
         From  YourTable
      ) Src
 Pivot (max(TierDesc) for ColNr in ([1],[2],[3]) ) pvt
```

> **EDIT 2**

```
Select Distinct 
       ColNr = row_number() over (partition by ContractID Order By TierDesc)
 From  Yourtable
```

Comment: one last thing, the first query is working fine but the order of the tier value is not right, i would like to show as tier1, tier2 etc...

Comment: @moe  We are ordering by TierDesc.   Perhaps edit your questions and provide a better sample data